# Unknown code in Java

Tags: java, class, for-loop, methods, iterator

I was browsing SO looking at questions in Java, and I came across some interesting code. 
Consider the following code:

```
class A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 13;
    found: {
        for (int x : new int[]{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
            if (n % x == 0) {
                System.out.println("" + n + " equals " + x + "*" + (n/x));
                break found;
            }
        System.out.println("" + n + " is a prime number");
    }
}
```

`}`

Please keep in mind that I am no veteran in Java, and by no means a professional programmer (So please point anything that I am clearly missing). Now, I am curious as to what this line means:

```
found: {
```

My first observation was that it was setting a variable, but upon further examination, I realized that I was clearly not. So what is it doing? Is there a name for this in Java?

Comment: Found is an alias for the loop. `break found` means to stop looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a labeled statement. [JLS-14.7. Labeled Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) says (in part)

> Statements may have *label* prefixes.
>
> ```
>  LabeledStatement:
>      Identifier : Statement
>
>  LabeledStatementNoShortIf:
>      Identifier : StatementNoShortIf
> ```
>
> The *`Identifier`* is declared to be the label of the immediately contained Statement.
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no `goto` statement; identifier statement labels are used with `break` ([§14.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)) or `continue` ([§14.16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16)) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

It's generally used with nested loops, to `break` from an inner loop.

```
out: for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (j == 1) {
            break out;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am quite confused, can you call labels like methods?

Comment: Which `loop` should stop when `j` is `1`. Or `continue`, if we try it with that. You can use labels to control which loop you `continue` or `break`. Usually when you can terminate the current context and proceed with the outer context.

Comment: Frisch Could you not just use a nested `for loop` with the inner containing a `break` statement? What is the advantage of using a label over nested loops?

Comment: @Matthewacon That would only break the inner loop.

Comment: The above example terminates the outer loop. How would breaking in the inner loop do that? Read the JLS quotes again.

Comment: Oh, so in the instance where I am using a `for loop` with a label, if there is a `break` statement anywhere in the `loop` that is executed, it would `break` out of all higher level loops (if any)?

Comment: If you used a labeled break, yes. If you used a raw break it would break from the inner loop. And it would have been faster to try it, then it was to ask (not that I particularly mind, but you would have known faster).

Answer (score 2):

it is a label, like that sweet sweet GOTO statement of days past.  I have never seen this used in practice.

Comment: I have. To control nested loop termination.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I would be most interested in the context that it was used, care to share :D

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32793478/2970947) is one example (*post hoc ergo propter hoc*).

Answer (score 1):

It acts like a GOTO, here are some example:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if(i == 5)
            break;
    }
```

Print :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Then

```
    badGoto:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            System.out.println(j+"j");
            if(i == 1)
                break badGoto;
        }
    }
```

Print:

```
0
0j
1j
1
0j
```

Answer (score 1):

The `found` part is called a label. Do you see that there is a statement

```
break found;
```

later in the code? That is where you use the label. `found` is labeling the for loop. Next time, when you want to say the for loop, say `found`. Thus, the `break` statement means: break out of the for loop.

You say, "Why can't I just write `break;`?". Sometimes we use nested loops. In those cases, labels are important. If you want to break the outer loop from the inner loop, you can't just write a simple `break;`. Because it will break only the inner loop but not the outer one. When the outer loop's iteration is finished, the inner loop will be executed again. You can add a label to the outer loop, maybe call it `outer`, and write `break outer;` from the inner loop.

But I have never written any code that uses this. I never terminate my loops with labels. So there might be a lot of programmers that don't know this feature!