# Can't stop while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, break

In this game that I created I ran into a problem. It all works great except that if you fail for some reason the game just restarts and that's not what I want. I want to display what I have it set to display and then break the loop, for some reason the `break;` isn't working.
Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame1_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("Pick a number to guess between: ");
        int userNumber = input.nextInt();

        int random = rand.nextInt(userNumber);

       if (random < 1) {
            random = random + 1;
       } else if (random > userNumber) {
            random = random - 1;
       }

        while (true) {
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out.print("Pick the amount of attempts you would like to have (Max of 10 attempts): ");
            int userAttempts = input.nextInt();

          if (userAttempts > 10) {
             System.out.println("To Many Attempts");
             System.out.println("");
          } else if (userAttempts <= 10) {

            System.out.println("Version: 1.3");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("You have " + userAttempts + " attempts to guess the number or else you fail. Goodluck!");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Type 'begin' to Begin!");
            String start = input.next();
            System.out.print('\f');

            if (start.equals("begin")) {
            for(int i=1; i<userAttempts + 1; i++) {
              System.out.print("Enter a number between 1-" + userNumber + ": ");
              int number = input.nextInt();

              if (number > random) {
                System.out.println("Too Big");
                System.out.println("");
              } else if (number < random) {
                System.out.println("Too Small");
                System.out.println("");
              } else if (number == random) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
               break;
              }

              if (i == userAttempts) {
               System.out.println("You have failed");
               System.out.println("Number Was: " + random);
               break;
              }
            }
          } else if (!start.equals("begin")) {
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out.println("Incorrect Command");
            System.out.println("Please Exit Console And Retry");
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception i.e. `InputMismatchException`

Comment: Your break (which is inside the forloop) is breaking the for loop, not the while loop.

Comment: A break exits the current loop. Since you're executing inside the for loop it's breaking the for loop, not the while loop. The solution by elliot will work, however conventionally it's better to do as James posted, and use a variable in your while loop that you set to false to stop. What I would add to James' answer is to break right after setting the variable to exit the for loop, this way the code doesn't run anymore of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

With nested loops if you want to `break` the outer loop you might add a label prefix<sup>1</sup>.

```
game: while (true) {
```

then you could

```
break game;
```

to terminate the statement that is labeled `game`.

<sup>1<sub>See also [JLS-14.7. Labeled Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) which says (in part) *Statements may have* ***label*** *prefixes.*</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a variable to check if you should continue the loop. Something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("Pick a number to guess between: ");
        int userNumber = input.nextInt();

        int random = rand.nextInt(userNumber);

        if (random < 1) {
            random = random + 1;
        } else if (random > userNumber) {
            random = random - 1;
        }

        boolean continueGame = true;
        while (continueGame) {
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out
                    .print("Pick the amount of attempts you would like to have (Max of 10 attempts): ");
            int userAttempts = input.nextInt();

            if (userAttempts > 10) {
                System.out.println("To Many Attempts");
                System.out.println("");
            } else if (userAttempts <= 10) {

                System.out.println("Version: 1.3");
                System.out
                        .println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out
                        .println("You have "
                                + userAttempts
                                + " attempts to guess the number or else you fail. Goodluck!");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Type 'begin' to Begin!");
                String start = input.next();
                System.out.print('\f');

                if (start.equals("begin")) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < userAttempts + 1; i++) {
                        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1-"
                                + userNumber + ": ");
                        int number = input.nextInt();

                        if (number > random) {
                            System.out.println("Too Big");
                            System.out.println("");
                        } else if (number < random) {
                            System.out.println("Too Small");
                            System.out.println("");
                        } else if (number == random) {
                            System.out.println("Correct!");
                            continueGame = false;
                        }

                        if (i == userAttempts) {
                            System.out.println("You have failed");
                            System.out.println("Number Was: " + random);
                            continueGame = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else { //You may remove if (!start.equals("begin")) check 
                         //as the result is either true or false and you 
                         //have checked the true condition in if
                    System.out.print('\f');
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Command");
                    System.out.println("Please Exit Console And Retry");
                    continueGame = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the outer loop as well the inner loops

Take a look : (variable `failattempt`)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame1_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("Pick a number to guess between: ");
        int userNumber = input.nextInt();

        int random = rand.nextInt(userNumber);

       if (random < 1) {
            random = random + 1;
       } else if (random > userNumber) {
            random = random - 1;
       }

        boolean failattempt = false;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out.print("Pick the amount of attempts you would like to have (Max of 10 attempts): ");
            int userAttempts = input.nextInt();

          if (userAttempts > 10) {
             System.out.println("To Many Attempts");
             System.out.println("");
          } else if (userAttempts <= 10) {

            System.out.println("Version: 1.3");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("You have " + userAttempts + " attempts to guess the number or else you fail. Goodluck!");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Type 'begin' to Begin!");
            String start = input.next();
            System.out.print('\f');

            if (start.equals("begin")) {
            for(int i=1; i<userAttempts + 1; i++) {
              System.out.print("Enter a number between 1-" + userNumber + ": ");
              int number = input.nextInt();

              if (number > random) {
                System.out.println("Too Big");
                System.out.println("");
              } else if (number < random) {
                System.out.println("Too Small");
                System.out.println("");
              } else if (number == random) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
               break;
              }

              if (i == userAttempts) {
               System.out.println("You have failed");
               System.out.println("Number Was: " + random);
               failattempt = true;
               break;
              }
            }
            if (failattempt == true)
                break;
          } else if (!start.equals("begin")) {
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out.println("Incorrect Command");
            System.out.println("Please Exit Console And Retry");
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```